# knockout dynamically replace a object in an observable array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have knockout observable array like

```
var viewModel={
       people : ko.observableArray([
            { name: 'Bert' },
            { name: 'Charles' },
            { name: 'Denise' }
        ])};
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

with foreach binding i have displayed the array in a table
now i want to chane the first row of the table dynamically
using the array index 
i tryed `(viewModel.people.name[0]("new value");` it doesn't work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An observableArray is really an observable with extra additional array-like features, not a plain javascript array. So to get to your array you need to resolve the observable first :

```
viewModel.people()[0].name = "new value";
```

---

edit

If you want that a change in the .name property of one of the object in the array triggers a modification to the page, the property will need to be observable too.
Something like this:

```
var viewModel={
    people : ko.observableArray([
        { name: ko.observable('Bert') },
        { name: ko.observable('Charles') },
        { name: ko.observable('Denise') }
    ])};

// Update:
viewModel.people()[0].name("new value");
```

Comment: i tried its not changing the value ,viewModel.people()[0].name is giving the value when i used in an alert

Comment: it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dUULM/4/

don't forget that simply putting an object into an [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) doesn’t make all of that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

Comment: @PaulValla exactly thanks,viewModel.people()[0]=({name:'Some new value'}); it worked, thing is that updation is not visible without reloading the viewmodel again.